# can't access docker-compose volume after restart my service systemd

Tags: mongodb, docker, permissions, docker-compose, systemd

I create docker-compose with two services: python api and mongodb, after starting first-time `sudo docker-compose up` it creates a file for mongo db inside `\data`, after `sudo docker-compose down` and again `sudo docker-compose up` mongo can't access files in \data.
Obviously something wrong with permissions, but I don't know what exactly.

But if I just stop containers without `sudo docker-compose down` and `sudo docker-compose up` again everything is ok.

So everything goes wrong after `down`

systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=RestAPI imp
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/entrant/myserv
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose down
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'
services:
 web_dev:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
   - .:/app
  environment:
   - ENV=PROD
   - DATABASE_URL=mongodb://mongodb:27017/myserv?authSource=admin&replicaSet=myrepl
  depends_on:
   - mongodb
  command: deploy/wait-for-it.sh mongodb:27017 -- gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080 index:api.app -w 9
 mongodb:
  image: mongo:4.0.12-xenial
  container_name: "mongodb"
  environment:
   - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=myserv
   - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
   - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
  volumes:
   - ./data/db:/data/db
  ports:
   - 27017:27017
  command: bash -c "
      mongod --fork --replSet myrepl --bind_ip_all --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null
      && mongo --eval 'rs.initiate()'
      && mongod --shutdown
      && mongod --replSet myrepl --bind_ip_all --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null
    "
networks:
 default:
  name: web_dev
```

Comment: Here `data` is a directory in you container or host or a volume?

Comment: Added some edits

Comment: It looks like you are mounting the ./data/db folder also in the web container. can you mount the web server to a separate folder something like ./app/

Comment: no, it is about what is going on after `docker-compose down` that I cant access previous data